# how to install global package in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

One of my apps in Heroku have a memory leak in it, therefore I'm looking for a way to take `heap snapshot` there.

I found several `node-remote-debugging` packages, but [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) looks the most promising, but it needs to be installed globally.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any info about how to install a **global dependency** on Heroku.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you think it needs to be installed globally?

I'd recommend following these guidelines:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#ensure-you-aren-t-relying-on-untracked-dependencies

  npm install --save --save-exact node-inspector

At that point, it's accessible from npm scripts directly, or from node_modules/.bin/whatever outside of npm.

Keep in mind that you're limited to a single open port on Heroku (currently) so you probably won't be able to use node-inspector without some hacking (like reverse tunnel buildpacks). It may be easier to use the heapdump module to get heap snapshots:

- https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump

Comment: I managed to fix the leak without heap snapshot, the problem was that I wrote files to **temp** folder instead of writing them to **tmp** 
*apparently writing files to folders other than tmp/* and log/* still works but consider as a swap memory and not written to the disk.
so.. I guess that if someone will ever encounter this question, remember to write the snapshots to tmp folder (or directly to S3) or you will make things worse.